# How to install a npm package from local folder and develop on both the folder simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

I am working on a React project and using Webpack to compile the code. This project contains a lot of common components which is installed in other projects across the organisation using [npm install private git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509669/how-to-install-an-npm-package-from-github-directly).

Package.json of other project looks like this:

`"@mypackage/my-package-name": "git+ssh://git@github.com:git-handle/git-repo.git",`

And in Webpack config I am compiling it by excluding it from node modules and it works fine.

```
module: {
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules(?!\/@mypackage))/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['@babel/react'],
        },
      },
    ],
  },
 ],
},
```

Now when I want to update the code of common component from the global package I have to reinstall the whole package to check the changes.

One workaround for that is to edit the node_modules but then I have to redo those changes to my global package and again do the reinstalling process at the end ( also it doesn't keep the git history to track what changes needs to be done ).

I have came across [npm install from local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50155052/install-access-a-local-folder-as-a-npm-module) and [npm link local folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088795/installing-a-local-module-using-npm) answer but facing the same issue which is not resolved

Updated package.json

`"@mypackage/my-package-name": "file:../my-package-name"`

I got the following errors

`Module not found: Can't resolve '@mypackage/my-package-name/Navbar' in 'path/to/folder/'`

`SassError: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap/variables`

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'js-cookie'`

These errors are may due to an incomplete compilation of code from local folder.

My folder structure is something like this

```
= (my-package)
  - package.json
  - ...
  = src
    - index.js
= (other-project)
  - package.json
  - ...
  = src
    - index.js
```

I am looking for a solution by which I can point the package to a local folder( mypackage global folder ) and synchronize the changes in both the projects.

Comment: have you ever added the `@` to your `my-package` folder?

Comment: No, I added it to the package name in my package.json